# Angular 1 http service for all components

Tags: angular

For each component I create I'm creating a service for it for http requests. I cannot have only one since i'm passing the `<udcInterface[]>` as below:

```
getResponce() {
  return this.http.get<udcInterface[]>(`${this.baseLink}`, 
                                       this.httpOptionsWithToken)
}
```

is there a way where I can pass it in the function? something like the below (I know that it is wrong)

```
getResponce(something) {
    return this.http.get<something[]>(`${this.baseLink}`, 
                                      this.httpOptionsWithToken)
}
```

for each component, I'm creating the same HTTP request code and only changing `<udcInterface[]>`

Comment: So you mean passing the return type of the http call?

Comment: Yes, so better than creating a new service for each component where I pass the return type(interface) , I can create only one service that will handle all http calls with types passed as arguments

Answer (score 2):

In the `<>` brackets you're just declaring the return type of the generic function `get`. You can make any function generic using these brackets.

```js
  getResponce<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(`${this.baseLink}`, this.httpOptionsWithToken);
  }
```

Then to call the function it's the same as you did with `get`

```js
const response = this.getResponce<string[]>();
```